# Setting Cookie for WebForms app in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, webforms

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".MyWebSite" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" loginUrl="Login" timeout="60" path="/" defaultUrl="~/Pages/Landing.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
```

`Login` is an MVC route that is working.

From within my Login `POST` method, assuming the username/password are valid:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true);
```

Is this correct?  Does this do the same thing that a WebForms Login control code would do?  It seems to work fine, but I want to make sure that I'm not overlooking something here.

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine for mvc too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, that is fine for MVC, too.

A longer answer is - the authentication module doesn't really care what handler is executed in the pipeline. The forms authentication module cares for a cookie and if it sees one, it sets `HttpContext.Current.User` accordingly. What happends in a handler, whether it is MVC, WebForms page, a WCF service, a WebApi service or anything else, the identity is set in the very same way.

Comment: I love .NET.  Thanks for the confirmation.